# Seaborn clustermap as a subplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

The [seaborn clustermap](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) seems to be a  figure-level plot which creates its own figure and axes internally.

I would like to use a cluster as a subplot, to be able to add extra plots on the same figure (for instance, a boxplot at the top of the heatmap).

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Example for a clustermap:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

nb_features = 20

tmp = [v for v in zip(np.repeat(['A', 'B'], 5), 
       np.hstack([range(5), range(5)]))]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tmp)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([np.random.rand(5, nb_features) + 1, 
                             np.random.rand(5, nb_features) - 1]), index=index).T

# Returns a seaborn.matrix.ClusterGrid
cax = sns.clustermap(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Post a proper MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some space to the figure, e.g. via `subplots_adjust()`.
Then you can add a new axis via `fig.add_axes([x, y, width, height])` (expressed in [figure coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html)).

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)
g.fig.set_size_inches(20, 10)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.5)
ax = g.fig.add_axes([0.55, 0.05, 0.42, 0.92])
ax.plot(np.random.randn(1000).cumsum())
plt.plot()
```

[image: example clustermap with new subplot]