# How to add multiple sns.clustermap in a subplot?

Tags: python

My question is basically the title of this! I've tried using the `ax` parameter, but that doesn't work, since `sns.clustermap` already creates multiple axes. This question is very similar to the following post: [Seaborn clustermap as a subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800299/seaborn-clustermap-as-a-subplot), however it only describes how to add sns.clustermap to a subplot with a lineplot. Thank you in advance!